# Entity Framework 7 Core emulate not supported migration operation

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I want use user EF 7 + migration + SQLite. But not all operation is supported.

Can I perform not supported operation manually?

Sample I want remove column.

I add new  migration with **migrationBuilder.DropColumn** (SQLite not support DropColumn)

Can I write code for apply migration with skip DropColumn or run my sql instead of

Answer (score 0):

Solution for SQLite with skip DropColumn

```cs
public class DB: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator, SqliteMigrationsSqlGeneratorExt>();
    }
}

public class SqliteMigrationsSqlGeneratorExt: SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    public override IReadOnlyList<MigrationCommand> Generate(IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> operations, IModel model = null)
    {
        //Remover DropColumn from operations
        return operations;
    }
}
```